# Mulitype selection in JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

My code:

```
JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
dialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
dialog.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File arg0) {
        return arg0.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("png")||
                arg0.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("jpg");
    }
});
File[] file = dialog.getSelectedFiles();
```

When the program is running, I can't select more than 1 file.

[image]

Comment: Please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set MultiSelection enable before open the dialog.

```
dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);  
dialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);
```

same for setting filefilter.

```
JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
dialog.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File arg0) {
        return arg0.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("png")
                || arg0.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("jpg");
    }

});
dialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);//open it last
File[] file = dialog.getSelectedFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your `dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);` above your `dialog.showOpenDialog(rootPane);` to make this work.  Also if you do not need the description you can simplify your code as shown below.  Hope this helps.

```
`JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
 dialog.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
 dialog.showOpenDialog(null);
 dialog.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("pngFilter", "png"));
 dialog.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpgFilter", "jpg"));
 File[] file = dialog.getSelectedFiles();`
```